# How to insert '|' between two words?

Tags: linux

I have to find average of marks in the following way:

The input file format is

```
Student name#class#marks1#marks2
```

The output file format is

```
Student name|class|marks 1|marks 2|average marks
```

I am using Ubuntu and I am very new in shell scripting. I know the normal way of coding the above in python but not in this above specific format. Please help.

Also, please tell if there is any way of writing the above program without using `echo` command.

Comment: you need to look for "sed"

Comment: "there is any way of writing the above program without using echo command" why would you put such a limit to your scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Your spec is *cough* rather lacking, but ...

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#";ORS="|"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,($3+$4)/2 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/#/|/g'
```

will substitute every `#` for a `|`.

Example:

```
cat <<EOF >file.txt
Student name#class#marks1#marks2
EOF

sed -i 's/#/|/g' file.txt

cat file.txt
```